# css in menu not working

Tags: css, html-table

When iam about to change the color of the following the code doesn't work and the menu color appears in #fff i.e white . can anyone help me out

```
#mainnav ul li::before{
        font-family: Fontawesome;
        color: #d65050;
        float: left;
        margin: 5px 5px 0 0;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 1;
        font-weight: 400;
    }
```

My html code for this is in www.tradestar.com

This css is for ul but not background . Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add the HTML code too?

Comment: We need the html to which this css applies.

Comment: Could you please post the HTML code as well?

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean background-color.

Just change your

```
color: #d65050;
```

to

```
background-color: #d65050;
```